# MySQL plans and SUBQUERY vs DEPENDENT SUBQUERY performance

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

We are in the midsts of migrating from MySql 5.7 to 8. We have two of our development systems over, and most everything seems to be working well. One place where we have found an issue is that we have a query which on our production server takes < 2 seconds, but on both of our converted systems, not takes more than 50 seconds.

One thing that we noticed in the plans that are different, is that on our production system, the `select_type` for the steps are:

| id | select_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |
| 3 | SUBQUERY |
| 3 | SUBQUERY |
| 3 | SUBQUERY |
| 3 | SUBQUERY |

Where as in our converted databases (8.0) the plan looks like

| id | select_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |

The `table`, `type`, `key` and `ref` columns are identical. The only other difference appears to be in the `Extra` column, but I'm not sure what could cause those differences.

Any idea what impact having some of those lines be DEPENDENT SUBQUERY vs SUBQUERY?

The basics of the query are:

```
SELECT e.ent_id, e.status_id, COUNT(e.id) AS cnt
FROM Events e
WHERE
e.ent_id IN (1)
AND
NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT eam.acct
    FROM EventAccountMapping eam
    WHERE 
      eam.event_id = e.id AND
      eam.account NOT IN
      (
          SELECT uam.account
          FROM UserAccountMapping uam
          WHERE uam.user_id = 109
      )
)
```

Note that this part is not dependent on any other part of the query:

```
SELECT uam.account
FROM UserAccountMapping uam
WHERE uam.user_id = 109
```

Yet it looks like the optimizer is treating this as a dependent query. Additionally, if I replace that subquery with the results of the query, the query runs in 1 second. i.e.

```
eam.account NOT IN
(
     'abc',
     'def',
     'ghi'
)
```

For some reason, the optimizer is thinking that getting the list of `UserAccountMappings` is dependent on the rest of the query.

Comment: We need to see the query and the rest of the lines.  _Probably_ the tables were 'used' in a different order because the Optimizer felt like it.

Comment: One thing to note, that I believe is the root of the issue, is that in 5.7, the optimizer sees this as 3 queries, a primary, a dependant, and a simple subquery, but in 8.0, this is seen as a primary and the rest are all dependent subqueries, even though the last part of the query is not dependent

Comment: Are you certain the index's are conformed between your Production and Development environments? Your dev environment might not be index'd therefore runs a whole lot slower

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the output of the optimizers list from both the versions you are using probably by enabling or disabling the one of the optimizers which is a possible reason for a different query plan.

select @@optimizer_switch;

Its like shooting in the dark with the information being shared here.

a) Still did you try forcing indexes to force optimizer to choose the index which is giving better performance in 5.7.
b) did you match the cardinality of the data set between 5.7 and 8.0 environment
c) You could try manipulating the index stats that would force optimizer to choose a different index instead of the default index.
d) Do **explain format=json** This would give you more reasons on query cost and what's exactly happening while query execution.

Comment: I looked at the optimizer switches, and all of the switches returned by our prod (5.7) are the same as out dev (5.8) server. The 5.8 server has a couple of additional ones.

Comment: Its like shooting in the dark with the information being shared here. 

a) Still did you try forcing indexes to force optimizer to choose the index which is giving better performance in 5.7.
b) did you match the cardinality of the data set between 5.7 and 8.0 environment
c) You could try manipulating the index stats that would force optimizer to choose a different index instead of the default index.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch.  Double negative.  Makes my brain hurt.

These indexes may help:

```
e:  INDEX(ent_id,  status_id)
uam:  INDEX(user_id,  account)
eam:  INDEX(event_id, account,  acct)
```

After adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

Please show us *the entire* `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I dont believe its an indexing issue. Nothing in the plan is pointing to a scan. I think its that 8.0 implements “ANTIJOIN” and that is fouling up the optimizer.

Comment: However, indexes can distract it from other things.